# Wordpress theme language

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

I have a site on wordpress using the subway theme, and most of the site is in Spanish, but I can't figure out how to change the language of the abbreviation of the months on "recent posts", I tried the wp-includes/locale.php that has those instructions to assign the abbreviations to the full word, but it doesn't change anything. What am I missing? or is it another file I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Dont touch the Core!

To localize plugins or themes, check out the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers